# filter messages coming from a specific type of camel endpoint

Tags: apache-camel

lets say, I have

```
from("direct:start").filter("...")
```

How can I filter out messages coming from an endpoint like smtp? Is there a way to check the type of the previous endpoint?

---

Edit: As per advice from vikingsteve, I have implemented the code this way:

```
from("direct:source")
        .process(new Processor() {

            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.setProperty("source", "smtps");
            }

        })
        .to("direct:start");


from("direct:start").filter(
                new Predicate() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
                        if(exchange.getProperty("source") == "smtps")
                            return true;
                        else
                        return false;
                    }}));
```

Comment: Super! Please also remember to use `.equals` (instead of `==`) when comparing strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would normally set an exchange property if you need to identify some information about the original message (such as where it came from, or some other metadata not contained in the body).

```
from("smtp:...").setProperty("source", "smtp").to("...")
```

edit: here's a simpler version of your solution, I havent tested it, but it might work like this:

```
from("direct:source")
    .setProperty("source", "smtps")
    .to("direct:start");


from("direct:start")                
    .filter(exchangeProperty("source").isEqualTo("smtp"))
```